# how i can pass argument to windows 2003 batch file and execute it from unix-aix and return value to unix-aix

Tags: unix, command-line, windows-server-2003, aix

how i can pass argument to windows 2003 batch file and execute it from unix-aix and return value to unix-aix

Comment: I don't understand. Do you **1)** have a .bat/.cmd file you want to execute on AIX? or **2)** have two servers, a Windows 2003 server and an AIX server, and want to remotely execute a .bat/.cmd file on the Windows machine from the AIX machine?

Comment: The second option .... 
2) have two servers, a Windows 2003 server and an AIX server, and want to remotely execute a .bat/.cmd file on the Windows machine from the AIX machine .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure you have an SSH service running on Windows. If you don't you can install [Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX (SFU)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb463213.aspx).

Then you can issue a remote command using `rsh` (or `ssh`) from your UNIX server:

```
$ rsh -l user_name windows_host_name "C:\path\to\script.bat"
```

Comment: the result is host: name -l NOT FOUND ..... ????

Comment: ok i do it but when i enter the password the following result appear >>>>Permission denied, please try again

Comment: are you trying your windows username and password?

Comment: yes ... but i want to ask you if i should give windows user access on copssh ... if yes how i can do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Telnet](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Telnet) or [SSH](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Secure_Shell). SSH is highly recommended because Telnet is insecure. See [this page](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~smp/projects/ssh-windows/) to install OpenSSH server on Windows Server 2003. After installing it, you can connect to it from the AIX machine using `ssh <server-address>`, given that an ssh client is installed (most Unix systems have one installed by default). Once you're connected, you get the command line of the Windows machine, and you can run the batch file there.

Comment: ok i do it but when i enter the password the following result appear >>>>Permission denied, please try again.